# Add strings between curly braces using string formatter in c#

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a requirement to concat two string values and these values should be placed between curly braces, I'm trying to define string format as a constant and passing the string values, 
I have tried many formats but always am getting Invalid Input Parameter exception. Is that possible to do the following using string formatter ? if then how ?

```
private const string formatString = "'{'{0}'}''{'{1}'}'";

string str1 = "John";
string str2 = "John@Xmail.com";

string resultString = string.Format(formatString, str1, str2);
```

> **Expected Output**

{John}{John@Xmail.com}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must escape it using double curly braces.

```
private const string formatString = "{{{0}}}{{{1}}}";
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape `{` and `}` in order to use them on `string.Format`

```
private const string formatString = "{{{0}}}{{{1}}}";
```